# How to display specific div onclick using js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have multiple

with various div inside. On click of more or less a tag I want to display specific

i.e. display_on_click

And I want to add that class only for 2 minutes after that remove that  class and hide div

My HTML code as below:

```js
$('body').on("click", ".more, .less", function() {
  var obj = $(this);
  obj.closest('.product_info').find('.display_on_click').addClass('display_on_click_show');
});
```

```css
.display_on_click {
  display: none
}

.display_on_click.display_on_click_show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <ol class="item_wrapper">
    <li class="product_info">
      <div class="title">
        <h3>Title here</a>
      </div>
      <div class="incre_decre">
        <a class="more">+</a>
        <a class="less">+</a>
      </div>
      <div class="display_on_click">Updated</div>
    </li>
    <li class="product_info">
      <div class="title">
        <h3>Title here</a>
      </div>
      <div class="incre_decre">
        <a class="more">+</a>
        <a class="less">+</a>
      </div>
      <div class="display_on_click">Updated</div>
    </li>
    <li class="product_info">
      <div class="title">
        <h3>Title here</a>
      </div>
      <div class="incre_decre">
        <a class="more">+</a>
        <a class="less">+</a>
      </div>
      <div class="display_on_click">Updated</div>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Anyone have idea what I am doing wrong then let me know.
And I want to add that class only for 2 minutes after that remove that  class and hide

Comment: Your html does not contain any elements with the `qty-updated-info` class.

Comment: Thats was writing mistake .  display_on_click actually there

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
$('body').on("click", ".more, .less", function() {
  let parentLi = $(this).parent().parent();

  let elementToManipulate = obj.find('.display_on_click');
  elementToManipulate.addClass('display_on_click_show');

  setTimeout(()=> {
     elementToManipulate.removeClass('display_on_click_show')
  }, 120000);
});
```

Instead of using closests I'm grabbing the parent of the parent which is the `<li>`. You can use closest to grab it. Once I am in the parent li, I find the child with the .display... class (the elementToManipulate object).

Then I add the classes and create a setTimeout to remove the class after 120.000 miliseconds (60sec * 2 * 1000msec)

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onClick='OpenDiv'>Open</button>

function OpenDiv(){
    let div = document.getElementById('BoxOne')
    if (div.style.display == 'flex') {
        div.style.display = 'none';
    else
        div.style.display = 'flex';
}
```

I hope this will work

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.